# How to access already existing data in Realm cloud using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm

I’m using Realm for my Xamarin forms App.I have synced my data in Sql server with Realm cloud.Now I want to view the data which is there in Realm cloud in my Xamarin Forms App.
I used code

```
public ListsViewModel()
{

        LogoutCommand = new Command(Logout);
        AddressCommand = new Command(AddList);
        //TaskLists = new IQueryable<Address>();
        IQueryable<Address> TaskLists = Enumerable.Empty<Address>().AsQueryable();

        //AddList();
    }
private void AddList()
{

        _realm = Realm.GetInstance();

        TaskLists =  _realm.All<Address>();

        TaskLists.Count();


    }
```

My **TaskLists.Count()** gives **0**.But my **ROS has the data from sql server** and they both are in sync.And **I'm able to Login to my Realm Object Server** through my Xamarin Forms App.But my Xamarin Forms app is not syncing with my ROS that is the **data which is there in my Realm object server is not displaying in my APP**.I want to display the data of **Address** class in my App.**The data of address class is put through SQL server**.**I just Have to retrieve the data of Address class**.  I even tried using **SyncConfiguration**.

```
private async void AddList()
{
User user = null;
try
{
user = User.Current;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
HandleException(ex);
}

        if (user == null)
        {
            try
            {
                user = await NavigationService.Prompt<LoginViewModel, User>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var uri = user.ServerUri;
            Constants.Server.SyncHost = $"{uri.Host}:{uri.Port}";
        }

        var config = new SyncConfiguration(user, Constants.Server.SyncServerUri)
        {
            ObjectClasses = new[] { typeof(Address) }
        };

        _realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
        //_realm = Realm.GetInstance();

        TaskLists =  _realm.All<Address>();


        _realm.Write(() =>
        {
            _realm.Add(new Address { ID = 8, ZipCode = "Judson123" });
        });

        TaskLists.Count();


    }
```

Still I’m not able to fix it.Please Help me with this.

Comment: You need to set the right SyncConfiguration and log in

Comment: So @EpicPandaForce ur telling me to use
var config = new SyncConfiguration(user, Constants.Server.SyncServerUri)
                {
                    ObjectClasses = new[] { typeof(Task)}
                };

                _realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
instead of
 _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
Right?

Comment: I have done that aswell. I'm able to login but I'm not able to display the data inside the Address in my app.The syncing of data is not happening.